# Bevel doesn't work on all edges

Tags: bevel

I have a problem with bevel. Here u can see one half of the mesh bevels fine, but the other one doesn't work. I applied scale transform, removed doubles, recalculated normals, object wasn't mirrored, but it was extruded out of itself on the right half and on the left it was merged with another part, which is where it's not working. I tried creating new model and yes, basically, as long as I extrude geom it's fine, but where I make a loop and merge vertices it doesn't work. Pls help, I'm obviously missing smth and idk what :')
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check for internal faces and duplicated vertices

Comment: please attach your blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra face inside the geometry, if you delete it, the bevel should work.
[image]

Comment: Oohh.. I always kind of assumed that if u merge verteces the faces gonna merge too... I didn't know this^ was happening, thank u :)

Comment: Faces can be between any vertices, there is no reason they should be automatically deleted if they were created on those vertices.